# Multiple independent stages in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Is there a way to launch multiple independent stages in JavaFX? By independent I mean that the stages are all created from the main thread.

At the moment my application is more or less an algorithm where I would like to plot some charts and tables during execution (mainly to check whether the results are correct/ to debug).

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to create and show multiple stages independently, i.e. I would like to do something like this

```
public static void main(){
    double[] x = subfunction.dosomething();
    PlotUtil.plot(x); //creates a new window and shows some chart/table etc.
    double[] y = subfunction.dosomethingelse();
    PlotUtil.plot(y); //creates a new window and shows some chart/table etc.
    .....
}
```

which would allow to use `PlotUtil` as one would use the plotting functions in other scripting languages (like Matlab or R).

So the main question is how to "design" `PlotUtils`? So far I tried two things

1. PlotUtils uses Application.launch for each plot call (creating a new stage with a single scene every time) --> does not work as `Application.launch` can only be invoked once.
2. Create some kind of "Main Stage" during the first call to PlotUtils, get a reference to the created Application and start subsequent stages from there --> does not work as using `Application.launch(SomeClass.class)` I am not able to get a reference to the created Application instance.

What kind structure/design would allow me to implement such a PlotUtils function?

**Update 1:**

I came up with the following idea and was wondering whether there are any major mistakes in this solution.

Interface to be implemented by all "Plots"

```
public abstract class QPMApplication implements StageCreator {
   @Override
   public abstract  Stage createStage();
}
```

Plotting functionality:

```
public class PlotStage {
    public static boolean toolkitInialized = false;

    public static void plotStage(String title, QPMApplication stageCreator) {
        if (!toolkitInialized) {
            Thread appThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Application.launch(InitApp.class);
                }
            });
            appThread.start();
        }

        while (!toolkitInialized) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Stage stage = stageCreator.createStage();
                stage.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public static class InitApp extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
            toolkitInialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
public class PlotStageTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        QPMApplication qpm1 = new QPMApplication() {
            @Override
            public Stage createStage() {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                StackPane root = new StackPane();
                Label label1 = new Label("Label1");
                root.getChildren().add(label1);
                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
                stage.setTitle("First Stage");
                stage.setScene(scene);
                return stage;
            }
        };

        PlotStage.plotStage(qpm1);

        QPMApplication qpm2 = new QPMApplication() {
            @Override
            public Stage createStage() {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                StackPane root = new StackPane();
                Label label1 = new Label("Label2");
                root.getChildren().add(label1);
                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
                stage.setTitle("Second Stage");
                stage.setScene(scene);
                return stage;
            }
        };

        PlotStage.plotStage(qpm2);

        System.out.println("Done");

    }
}
```

Comment: Just create multiple `Stage` instances and call `show()` on them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But I still had to make sure that 1. the toolkit is initialized and 2. that the stages get created on the fx thread (and not on the main thread). I updated the post accordingly, further suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your overall application lifecycle. If I were writing  an R interface from scratch, my application `start(...)` method would display a console and show it in the primary stage. When the user enters a command, it would process the command (in an event handler) and either output to the same console, or (if it needed to display a graph, for example), create a new `Stage` to show the graph. Can you structure it like that? If so, it is pretty simple.

Comment: You are certainly right, but my use case is slightly different. First, and maybe most important I don't want the controlflow to be started/ driven by a JavaFX app. What I was rather looking for is a quick (and hopefuly not too dirty) way to plot some figures every now and than (like you would in an R/Matlab script to plot some intermediate results during debugging/development) without having to worry about the Toolkit beeing intialized, making sure to plot on the JavaFX thread and so on... anyway, I really appreciate the comments.

Comment: It's hard for me to see why you wouldn't just drive it with a JavaFX Application (even if that application did nothing else): you have to drive it with something, after all. But if you really can't do that, the "quick hack" to force the JavaFX Application to start, if it's not already started, is to create a `JFXPanel` on the AWT Event dispatch thread.

Comment: Ok. I will think about refactoring it to a JavaFX app or using the JFXPanel approach as you suggested. If you'd like, reformulate your comment(s) as an answer and I will accept it. Thx again.

Comment: Added answer with example (and updated with second example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest approach here would be just to refactor your application so that it is driven from the FX Application thread. For example, you could rewrite your original code block as

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStageIgnored) {
        double[] x = subfunction.dosomething();
        PlotUtil.plot(x); //creates a new window and shows some chart/table etc.
        double[] y = subfunction.dosomethingelse();
        PlotUtil.plot(y); //creates a new window and shows some chart/table etc.
        //  .....
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Now `PlotUtil.plot(...)` merely creates a `Stage`, puts a `Scene` in it, and `show()`s it.

This assumes the methods you're calling don't block, but if they do you just have to wrap them in a `Task` and call `PlotUtils.plot(...)` in the `onSucceeded` handler for the task.

If you really want to drive this from a non-JavaFX application, there's a fairly well-known hack to force the JavaFX Application thread to start if it's not already started, by creating a new `JFXPanel`. A `JFXPanel` should be created on the AWT event dispatch thread.

Here's a very basic example of the second technique. Start the application and type "show" into the console. (Type "exit" to exit.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Main {

    private JFXPanel jfxPanel ;

    public void run() throws Exception {
        boolean done = false ;
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (! done) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for command...");
                String command = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Got command: "+command);
                switch (command.toLowerCase()) {
                case "exit": 
                    done = true;
                    break ;
                case "show":
                    showWindow();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Unknown command: commands are \"show\" or \"exit\"");   
                }
            }
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }

    private void showWindow() throws Exception {
        ensureFXApplicationThreadRunning();
        Platform.runLater(this::_showWindow);
    }

    private void _showWindow() {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Button button = new Button("OK");
        button.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(button), 350, 75);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.toFront();
    }

    private void ensureFXApplicationThreadRunning() throws Exception {

        if (jfxPanel != null) return ;

        FutureTask<JFXPanel> fxThreadStarter = new FutureTask<>(() -> {
            return new JFXPanel();
        });
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(fxThreadStarter);
        jfxPanel = fxThreadStarter.get();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        System.out.println("Starting Main....");
        new Main().run();
    }

}
```

Here is something more along the lines I would actually follow, if I wanted the user to interact via the OS terminal (i.e. using `System.in`). This uses the first technique, where the application is driven by an FX `Application` subclass. Here I create two background threads, one to read commands from `System.in`, and one to process them, passing them via a `BlockingQueue`. Even though nothing is displayed in the main FX Application Thread, it is still a very bad idea to block that thread waiting for commands. While the threading adds a small level of complexity, this avoids the "`JFXPanel`" hack, and doesn't rely on there being an AWT implementation present.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class FXDriver extends Application {

    BlockingQueue<String> commands ;
    ExecutorService exec ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t ;
        });

        commands = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        Callable<Void> commandReadThread = () -> {
            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.print("Enter command: ");
                    commands.put(scanner.nextLine());
                }
            } 
        };

        Callable<Void> commandProcessingThread = () -> {
            while (true) {
                processCommand(commands.take());
            }
        };

        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        exec.submit(commandReadThread);
        exec.submit(commandProcessingThread);
    }

    private void processCommand(String command) {
        switch (command.toLowerCase()) {
        case "exit": 
            Platform.exit();
            break ;
        case "show":
            Platform.runLater(this::showWindow);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Unknown command: commands are \"show\" or \"exit\"");   
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        exec.shutdown();
    }

    private void showWindow() {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Button button = new Button("OK");
        button.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(button), 350, 75);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.toFront();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```